# Is it haram to tie a tiny knot around your finger to remember something constantly so that it becomes habit?

Tags: halal-haram, behavior

Is it haram to tie a tiny knot around your finger or wear a rubber band around your hand solely for the reason of trying to remember something constantly so that it becomes habit?

For example: A man ties a tiny string around his finger to remember him to make dhikr, and after three days, takes it off, for it has become habit.

Looking around, I have only found references to indicate that wearing ornaments such as these are normally haram to separate males from females.

Would the practice of using an ornament as a memory helper be halal or haram?

Comment: see my answer and link... http://alifta.org/fatawa/fatawaDetails.aspx?languagename=en&BookID=14&View=Page&PageNo=1&PageID=1369

Comment: That sounds like a good way to develop a habit you want. Why do you suspect it’s haram? Nothing sounds haram about it.

Comment: In western culture, prior to smartphones and at a time when writing was an art only few had been told, it was common to tie a not in the handkerchief, which was buried in the pockets of the trousers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it wouldn't be Haram (prohibited). Specially if you strive to use it for good deeds. (Of course, perhaps it would be Haram if it become such the matters which are Bid'ah, But on the whole, I reckon it is okay to do that for reminding your affairs, specially your positive affairs.)

Answer (score -1):

It can become a tathayyur if you count it as a luck-charming attitude.

Luck charming in any form is forbidden in islam..
It is a form of light shirk..

Read on Shahih Muslim hadith no. 537 for reference about tathayyur.

Of course if you don't put any believe that the behavior cause luck.. Just to do it for some act to make you remember, then its all good.

Please correct me if I am wrong.
I am still a learner..